# How to get url params value and pass it in url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I having url in query string like http://www.domain.com:3000/allot_room?floor=6&hostel=1&student=1.In that, how to get student parameter value using jquery.

I have used this code

```
var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
```

It shows like floor=6,hostel=1,student=1.In that how to get student parameter value.And I tried different codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `var url = window.location.search`

and from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location) -

**Get the value of a single window.location.search key:**

```
function loadPageVar (sVar) {
  return decodeURI(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURI(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
}

alert(loadPageVar("floor"));
alert(loadPageVar("student"));
```

[More about window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
window.location.search
```

[see mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.235.3A_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property.3A)